# MVC linq query and dropdown lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to get details from the database to be edited. It actually works fine, my problem is that I am also trying to populate data from the db to two dropdown lists (these dropdown lists work fine with the "create" ActionResult

Could you guys kindly provide some examples on how to include the dropdown lists in the controller to be passed to the view?

Please see below: the area within comments (//) is what I want to do, but it only brings the fields empty in the view. The area outside the comments works fine (brings the details from the database, without the dropdown lists, though).

```
 // GET: /PropertiesHut/EditRent/3
    public ActionResult EditRent(int id)
    {
        //AdDetail ad = db.AdDetails.Single(a => a.AdType == id);

        //var vm = new InsertAd()
        //     {
        //         AdDetail = ad,
        //         PropertyType = new SelectList(db.PropertyTypes.OrderBy(o =>
        //           o.PropertyName).ToList(), "PropertyId", "PropertyName"),

        //         State = new SelectList(db.States.OrderBy(o =>
        //           o.StateShortName).ToList(), "StateId", "StateShortName")
        //     };
        //return View(vm);
```

// THIS IS WHAT WORKS

```
        var viewModel = from a in db.AdDetails
                        where a.AdType == id
                        select a;

        return View(viewModel.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

Comment: Put the contents of the dropdown box into the ViewBag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
ViewBag.RgnId = new SelectList(
     _db.Regions
     .OrderBy(r => r.name)
     .Select(x => new { x.id, x.name }), "id", "name", model.RgnId);
```

HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RgnId, (SelectList)ViewBag.RgnId, "Any Region")
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! And my return view will be the same? All that i need is to add that below the linq query? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, your return view will remain the same.  And the first code snippet has the LINQ query in it, you obviously have to change it out with yours.  As you can see, my model has a property "RgnId", and I name the ViewBag entry the same thing (ViewBag.RgnId), but I don't think you absolutely have to, but I found it easier if they matched.

Comment: Mate, thanks for your help and patience in explaining this to a newbie. thank you very much. It is working now!

Comment: No problem, we were all newbies once!